# ValueEventListener not triggering in Redmi 4

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

addValueEventListener(this) is not working in RedMI 4. If anyone came accross this please help me in this scenario.
The same code working all other devices like MOTO G3, SAMSUNG, and etc..

```
query.addValueEventListener(this);

@Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Leagues league = postSnapshot.getValue(Leagues.class);
            mLeagues.put(league.getId(),league);
        }
        adapter.adapterNotifyDataSetChanged(mLeagues);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
```

Comment: did u implement valueventlistener?

Comment: @PeterHaddad yes , i did that

Comment: okay how is not working? Is there any error?

Comment: @PeterHaddad There is no error . I am trying to debug but listener is not working.Callback is not coming